# What's the alternative to WebRequestHandler in .NET Core?

Tags: .net-core, system.net.httpwebrequest

I was using the **WebRequestHandler** for setting the **CachePolicy** and **AuthenticationLevel** in my full stack .NET application. Now I am migrating my application to .NET core and can't find an alternative to these properties or the WebRequestHandler. Any help? Following is my usage:

```
        var httpClientHandler = new WebRequestHandler
        {
            UseProxy = true,
            UseCookies = false,
            CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore),
            AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired
        };
```

Comment: You could try HttpClientHandler class (pass it as arg to HttpClient .ctor). But it doesn't have CachePolicy and AuthenticationLevel. I guess your solution may not lie in one handler instance. Btw, I use this to bypass SSL certificate errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## CachePolicy:

There is no equivalent to CachePolicy in .NET Core. However, .NET Core is equivalent to RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache. I confirmed that in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/19963).

So while there is no built-in CachePolicy, this design enables you to build your own cache on top of HttpClient using any policy you like.

## AuthenticationLevel:

WebRequest in .NET Core offers an AuthenticationLevel property, but that won't help you much if you need to use HttpClient.

You could implement a custom HttpMessageHandler to pass into HttpClient that supports AuthenticationLevel. To make it easier to implement, you could base it off an existing HttpMessageHandler such as the [Windows one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/6dd451f51451a7d0ceea6104b51bd17005e9a0e6/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.Windows.cs).