# I can't install the package System.Net.Http.WebRequest

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-package

I can't install the package `System.Net.Http.WebRequest`. Help!

```
$ dotnet add package System.Net.Http.WebRequest
  Writing /tmp/tmp91vAjR.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest' into project '/home/porton/Projects/ii/BravoDB/BravoDBDebug/BravoDBDebug.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for /home/porton/Projects/ii/BravoDB/BravoDBDebug/BravoDBDebug.csproj...
info :   GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http.webrequest/index.json
info :   NotFound https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/system.net.http.webrequest/index.json 1264ms
error: Unable to find package System.Net.Http.WebRequest. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
error: Package 'System.Net.Http.WebRequest' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '/home/porton/Projects/ii/BravoDB/BravoDBDebug/BravoDBDebug.csproj'.
```

Comment: Huh. If you're talking about `System.Net.HttpWebRequest`, then it's not a NuGet package. Though nowadays I would expect you'd want to use `HttpClient`.

Comment: @John Does it mean that I need to install `System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll
` manually (not through NuGet)?

Comment: @porton you need to find Nuget package which contains that binary and install it through package manager

Comment: I agree with John on `HttpClient`. Here is a nice post about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: @John http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/0f52c5bf-b7a4-4720-9572-6159b1804d1d.aspx

Comment: It seems that `WebRequestHandler` is a _.NET Framework_ thing. Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272530/whats-the-alternative-to-webrequesthandler-in-net-core), and the fact that it's not available in the .NET Core docs, only the [.NET Framework docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.webrequesthandler?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-2.2).