# Unable to install System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I got below issue while executing my internal project
[image]

So I want to download System.Net.Http.WebRequest, But
I am getting below issue while downloading the package using visual studio PM

[image]

Comment: check your target framework, are you using .net standart or .net core?

and also afaik it is not a nuget package.

Comment: Get some help from comment section of [I can't install the package System.Net.Http.WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321014/i-cant-install-the-package-system-net-http-webrequest)

Comment: Are you creating a .net or .Net Framework program. If you add it in the reference, could it solve the issue? i.stack.imgur.com/5HJyg.png

Comment: I am creating a c# application using .Net 7.0

Comment: Trying to create a c# application using .net framework. And add System.Net.Http.WebRequest in the reference. Have you tried using BorisD's suggestion?

Comment: One of the dll internally importing the System.Net.Http.WebReques which I can't modify it

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to download a package, those HTTP tools are in
`System.Net` namespace.

You can use `WebRequest.Create()` to create a new `WebRequest`.

**Anyway those methods are obsolete you should use HttpClient**

[Here is the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)