# Web request handler in .net core not found?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-framework-version

Basically I migrate from `.framework` to `.core` then I faced one error, Web request handler is not found. I searched alternate methods for `.netcore` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24613).

Is there any other method of registering web request handler?

```
error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebRequestHandler' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

---

```
public HttpClient ConfigureHttpClient(Configuration.Configuration config)
{
    WebRequestHandler mtlsHandler = new WebRequestHandler
    {
        UseProxy = true,
        UseCookies = false,
        CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore),
        AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequired,
        AllowAutoRedirect = false
    };
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24613

Comment: I guess you'd better share your code for us to see what is it actually doing. I don't believe you actually need it in the first place.

Comment: this does not require any code .this issue is already face by many other .i given link of two.

Answer (score 15):

In .netcore an equivalent would be `HttpClientHandler`, described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler?view=netcore-3.1). For some of the reasons mentioned in the [post](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24613) you have referenced already, `HttpClientHandler` exposes less options than `WebRequestHandler`.

Below is the code that configures `HttpClient` in a manner similar to your example, using `HttpClientHandler`:

```cs
var mtlsHandler = new HttpClientHandler {
   UseProxy = true,
   UseCookies = false,
   AllowAutoRedirect = false
   // CachePolicy = ... not supported and set to HttpRequestLevel.BypassCache equivalent, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21799
   // AuthenticationLevel = ... need to implement it yourself by deriving from HttpClientHandler, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272530/whats-the-alternative-to-webrequesthandler-in-net-core
};

var httpClient = new HttpClient(mtlsHandler);
```

Unfortunately there are 2 unresolved aspects remaining, both which require to do your own custom implementation on top of HttpClientHandler:

1. No support for `CachePolicy` other than BypassCache equivalent, discussed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21799).
2. No support for `AuthenticationLevel`, discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272530/whats-the-alternative-to-webrequesthandler-in-net-core).